# Adding vertical line and left brackate in array

Tags: formatting, matrices, arrays

I want to display my content like in image. I have considered array for this. Let me know if is there any better option for this.

```
\textbf {accesslog : } \textcolor{red}{ Array } 

   \begin{tabular}{ | l  c  r }

    date: & string & Data - da ocorrência. \\
    ObjectId: & Usuário - & que executou. \\
    action: & String - & Ação Executada.  \\ \\

    date: & string & Data - da ocorrência. \\
    ObjectId: & Usuário - & que executou. \\
    action: & String - & Ação Executada

    \end{tabular}
```

Currently it looks as here : https://www.sharelatex.com/project/53915feaeef2f99941486f56?r=380e068e&rs=ps&rm=d

Content should look like:

[image: array]

IS there any other possible way to show content like this?

Comment: You can nest `tabular` environments, so you could put the "access_log" text in one column and the existing tabular in a second column to get the effect you want.

Comment: @Thruston: yes, wipet's answer cleared this doubt. Are you saying the same as what wipet implemented? his answer is almost done, just issue is with access_log and array text

Comment: If you want the tall left braces then @wipet has the right approach.  But you could put what he has shown you into a tabular to get the other text at the front.

Comment: @Thruston: I created my doc with some change, here if you can help http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183784/latex-text-bold-center-and-link-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you needn't any tabular, if I see the picture well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\def\red#1{{\color{red}#1}}
\begin{document}

$$
\left(\vcenter{
  \hbox{$\left\{\
      \vcenter{\parindent=0pt
         \hbox{\textbf{date}: \red{string}  Data -- da ocorrncia.}
         \hbox{\textbf{ObjectId}: \red{Usuário} --  que executou.}
         \hbox{\textbf{action}: \red{String} --  Aço Executada.}
   }\right.$}
   \bigskip
   \hbox{$\left\{\
      \vcenter{\parindent=0pt
         \hbox{\textbf{date}: \red{string}  Data -- da ocorrncia.}
         \hbox{\textbf{ObjectId}: \red{Usuário} --  que executou.}
         \hbox{\textbf{action}: \red{String} --  Aço Executada.}
   }\right.$}
}\right.
$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I guess almost solved. In my code I put `access_log` and `array` in same line as matrix. But why the content way not inline? When I added `access_log` and array next to your code, it is also  appearing one line up the box

Comment: The adding the text before was a little exercise for you :). IMHO tex.stackexchange shares ideas and not primarly serves as a code generator: user sends picture and waits to the code without thinking. I was waiting for pure LaTeX solution here with many `\begin{minipage}`, `\end{minipage}`, `\begin{array}`, `\end{array}` etc. But such solution didn't arise here.

Comment: I created my doc with some change, here if you can help http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183784/latex-text-bold-center-and-link-issue

Answer (score 2):

Here is a LaTeX solution, using the `blkarray` package.  As you seem to declare programming variables and their type, I defined a `\variable` command, that takes as  single argument the variable name and its type, separated  by a colon, so as to have a syntax a close as possible from natural writing. It types the whole as you require (variable name in boldface, type in red), and if you forget the type, it types only the variable name. It requires the `xparse` package.

If you prefer a traditional syntax, the preamble contains another (commented) definition of `\variable`  with 2 arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{xparse}

%\newcommand*\variable[2]{\textbf{#1} : \textcolor{red}{#2}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\variable}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{:}}m}
{\varargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\varargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\textbf{#1}}{\textbf{#1}{ : }\textcolor{red}{#2}}}

\def\thickvrule{\vrule width 0.9pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ >{\sffamily}c}
\begin{blockarray}{rcl}%
 \begin{block}{>{\mbox{}}r!{\thickvrule}c@{\enspace}\{l}
 \variable{accesslog : Array}
& & \variable{date : string} -- Data da ocorrência. \\
& & \variable{ObjectId : Usuário} -- que executou. \\
 & & \variable{action : String} -- Ação Executada.\\
\end{block}
\begin{block}{>{\mbox{}}r!{\thickvrule}c@{\enspace}\{l}
& & \variable{date : string} -- Data da ocorrência. \\
& & \variable{ObjectId : Usuário} -- que executou. \\
& & \variable{action : String} -- Ação Executada.\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you please help me in addnig link to different page in same document here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183784/latex-text-bold-center-and-link-issue