# latex text bold, center and link issue

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyperref, formatting

I created one doc here. It has two pages, code seems correct as per me but there are some issue with it.

1. I used `\hfill` to put the title in center. IS it wrong?
2. In `email`, I made only this word `bold`. Why next text and content appearing in bold? though it has not be assigned
3. At `group_id` in page 1, I want to add link, when user click on it it should be take to `Group schema`. Is this possible to add link to next page(or any other page)?

Demonstration : https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5374a2ebeb2b8d651828ef64?r=380e068e&rs=ps&rm=d

Code:

```
\begin{document}   

\hfill \boldtitle{\textbf {User schema}}  \hfill    
{\setstretch{1.5}    
\textbf {ID : }  \textcolor{red}{ObjectId }- Id do registro \\
\textbf {Name: } \textcolor{red}{ String  } - Name co usuario \\
\textbf {date: } \textcolor{red}{ Date } - Date de Cadastro \\
\textbf {ren_date: } \textcolor{red}{ Date }  -  Data de     
\textbf {email: } \textcolor{red}{ String } - Lorem ipsum dolorsitamet, consecteturadipisicingelit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minimveniam, exercitationullamcolaborisnisi ut aliquipexeacommodoconsequat. Duisautereprehenderit in voluptatevelit esse cillumdolore eu fugiatnullapariatur. Occaecatcupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa quiofficiadeseruntmollit. 

$$
accesslog: \red { Array }
\left(\vcenter{
  \hbox{$\left\{\
      \vcenter{\parindent=0pt
         \hbox{\textbf{date}: \red{string}  Data -- da ocorrncia.}
         \hbox{\textbf{ObjectId}: \red{Usuário} --  que executou.}
         \hbox{\textbf{action}: \red{String} --  Aço Executada.}
   }\right.$}
   \bigskip
   \hbox{$\left\{\
      \vcenter{\parindent=0pt
         \hbox{\textbf{date}: \red{string}  Data -- da ocorrncia.}
         \hbox{\textbf{ObjectId}: \red{Usuário} --  que executou.}
         \hbox{\textbf{action}: \red{String} --  Aço Executada.}
   }\right.$}
}\right.
$$    
\textbf {group_id : } \textcolor{red}{ ObjectId } - Id do  grupo. 
}
```

Comment: The exercise wasn't done perfectly. Use `\hbox{accesslog: \red { Array }}` instead pure `accesslog: \red { Array }` and watch the difference. I'll not comment the rest of your code.

Comment: @wipet: thanks dude, silly mistake. CAn you please tell me how to add link at `group_id`? when user click on it, he should go to the page, where there is `group schema`

Answer (score 1):

For centering use the environment `center`. Use the mathmode only if needed. However, there are some errors in your code. A working one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf {User schema}
\end{center}

\setstretch{1.5}
\textbf {ID : }  \textcolor{red}{ObjectId }- Id do registro \\
\textbf {Name: } \textcolor{red}{ String  } - Name co usuario \\
\textbf {date: } \textcolor{red}{ Date } - Date de Cadastro \\
\textbf {ren\_date: } \textcolor{red}{ Date }  -  Data de 

\textbf {email: } \textcolor{red}{ String } - Lorem ipsum dolorsitamet, consecteturadipisicingelit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minimveniam, exercitationullamcolaborisnisi ut aliquipexeacommodoconsequat. Duisautereprehenderit in voluptatevelit esse cillumdolore eu fugiatnullapariatur. Occaecatcupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa quiofficiadeseruntmollit. 

\[
\text{accesslog: \textcolor{red}{ Array }}
  \left(
  \begin{array}{@{}ll}
  \left\{\begin{tabular}{l}
       \textbf{date}: \textcolor{red}{string}  Data -- da ocorrncia.\\
       \textbf{ObjectId}: \textcolor{red}{Usuário} --  que executou.\\
       \textbf{action}: \textcolor{red}{String} --  Aço Executada.\\
   \end{tabular}\right.\\
   ~\\
   \left\{
   \begin{tabular}{l}
         \textbf{date}: \textcolor{red}{string}  Data -- da ocorrncia.\\
         \textbf{ObjectId}: \textcolor{red}{Usuário} --  que executou.\\
         \textbf{action}: \textcolor{red}{String} --  Aço Executada.\\
   \end{tabular}\right.
   \end{array}
\right.
\]

\textbf {group\_id : } \textcolor{red}{ ObjectId } - Id do  grupo. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Hyperlinks can be set with `\label{..}` and `\href{text}{link}`. I do not really understand what you mean by "email".  In general it is set with `\url`.

Comment: I want to add link for another schema. Let's say `Group schema`. When user on `User schema` clicks on `Group_id`, he should go to the page where is 'User schema'

Comment: But is the page that contains "User schema" in the same document?

Comment: @cyclic: with `\href` you can jump to any place in the local doc.